# SignalR Communicate between asp.net and Console Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I'm relatively new to SignalR, however, I have been through lots of documentation and can't get this to work.

I have a fully working Hub working within SignalR that is implemented as a console application. I have also got a client working as another console application. However, I would also like to be able to send messages to the server from an asp.net application.

I send messages like this:

```
_hub.Invoke("SendMessage", "ExampleMessage").Wait();
```

I want it to work so that on a:

```
<asp:button onclick="Signalr_FireEvent"> (Not Real Code)
```

It sends a message like the one on top.

Client Application Info:

```
IHubProxy _hub;
string url = @"http://localhost:8080/";
var connection = new HubConnection(url);
_hub = connection.CreateHubProxy("Hub");
connection.Start().Wait();
_hub.On("ReceiveMessage", x => Console.WriteLine(x)); //On Receive Message Write To Console

_hub.Invoke("SendMessage", "$").Wait(); //Send LoggedIn Message once connected to server

string line = null;
while ((line = System.Console.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    _hub.Invoke("SendMessage", line).Wait();
}
Console.Read();
```

Comment: Its all the same concept (though TBH it probably makes more sense for the client browser to connect than the server...) What did you try and what didn't work?

Comment: I tried this using the onclick code for an asp:button however I never got anything coming up on the hub with a connection or an error message on the web browser so I presumed I was doing it incorrectly and due to their being no documentation on this I decided to ask here

Comment: You still need to be more specific. What code did you try that didn't work? Did you set some breakpoints and step through it? Check for exceptions in the output log? Without more information we can't help.

Comment: Ok, sorry I'll post some code in the morning on phone ATM. Thanks very much for your help so far

Comment: My suggestion is that you have a hub as the center, and then both the console app and the page (JavaScript usually) work as clients. You can easily forward messages between clients via the hub.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have a Hub class in your console server such as:

```
public class MyHub : Hub
{
    public void SendMessage(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Incoming message {0}", message);
    }
}
```

you can access the server from a client web application either through javascript:

```
<form runat="server">
    <div>
        <input type="button" id="sendmessage" value="Send from javascript" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Send from code behind" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
    </div>
</form>
<!--Script references. -->
<!--Reference the jQuery library. -->
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<!--Reference the SignalR library. -->
<script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.3.0.min.js"></script>
<!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
<script src="http://localhost:8080/signalr/hubs"></script>
<!--Add script to update the page and send messages.-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        //Set the hubs URL for the connection
        $.connection.hub.url = "http://localhost:8080/signalr";

        // Declare a proxy to reference the hub.
        var _hub = $.connection.myHub;

        // Start the connection.
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
                // Call the SendMessage method on the hub.
                _hub.server.sendMessage("$");
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

or code behind:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Set the hubs URL for the connection
    string url = "http://localhost:8080/signalr";

    // Declare a proxy to reference the hub.
    var connection = new HubConnection(url);

    var _hub = connection.CreateHubProxy("MyHub");

    connection.Start().Wait();

    _hub.Invoke("SendMessage", "$").Wait();
}
```

Please, note you need to have the following packages installed in the web application:

> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.JS
>
> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client

As a complete reference, please read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/deployment/tutorial-signalr-self-host which my answer was based on.